# How to fix the RuntimeError: builtin cannot be used as a value (with a dict) when creating checkpoints from jit in pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, jit

I want to compile arbitrary nn modules using jit.

In my code I compare my value to a dict and it throws an error.

```
        """
        if type(json_data) is dict:
                              ~~~~ <--- HERE
```

### To Reproduce

Simple, any code that has a comparison with a dict:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_data):
        if type(json_data) is dict:
            node_data = next(iter(json_data))
            assert type(json_data[node_data]) is list
            node_children = [cls.from_json(child) for child in json_data[node_data]]
            return Node(node_data, node_children)
        else:
            return Node(json_data)
```

### Expected behavior

Jit makes my checkpoint.

### Environment

- PyTorch / torchvision Version (e.g., 1.0 / 0.4.0): 1.7.1
- OS (e.g., Linux): mac os x
- How you installed PyTorch / torchvision (`conda`, `pip`, source): conda
- Build command you used (if compiling from source): conda
- Python version: 3.8
- CUDA/cuDNN version: CPU
- GPU models and configuration: CPU
- Any other relevant information: CPU

### Additional context

Compiling arbitrary custom nn modules to jit

error:

```
/Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/coq_gym/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --cmd-line --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 59213 --file /Users/brando/ML4Coq/playground/running_pytorch_ocaml/treenn2jit_ckpt.py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 203.7148.72)
1.7.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/coq_gym/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py", line 680, in compile_unbound_method
    create_methods_and_properties_from_stubs(concrete_type, (stub,), ())
  File "/Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/coq_gym/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py", line 304, in create_methods_and_properties_from_stubs
    concrete_type._create_methods_and_properties(property_defs, property_rcbs, method_defs, method_rcbs, method_defaults)
  File "/Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/coq_gym/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/annotations.py", line 330, in try_ann_to_type
    torch.jit._script._recursive_compile_class(ann, loc)
  File "/Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/coq_gym/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 1056, in _recursive_compile_class
    _compile_and_register_class(obj, rcb, _qual_name)
  File "/Users/brando/anaconda3/envs/coq_gym/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 64, in _compile_and_register_class
    torch._C._jit_script_class_compile(qualified_name, ast, defaults, rcb)
RuntimeError: 
builtin cannot be used as a value:
  File "/Users/brando/ML4Coq/ml4coq-proj/embeddings_zoo/extract_tactic_from_lasse_data.py", line 56
            term = string
        """
        if type(json_data) is dict:
                              ~~~~ <--- HERE
            node_data = next(iter(json_data))
            assert type(json_data[node_data]) is list
'Node.from_json' is being compiled since it was called from '__torch__.embeddings_zoo.extract_tactic_from_lasse_data.Node'
```

---

related:

- https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/3392
- https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1675